# getting JSON data from python several levels deep without names

Tags: python, json, csv, export-to-csv, readfile

So I've written some simple python code to do some web-scraping and I'm fairly noob, so i have a question.  I get my json data using:

```
results = response.json()
```

this causes me no problems with my site entered and parameters correct.

This JSON file has a few different groups, one of which is entitled 'moments', which itself goes fairly deep.

So, for example to get part of what i want, i can do a

```
print results['moments'][0][5]
```

but what i really want is to get

```
results['moments'][0][5]
results['moments'][1][5]
results['moments'][2][5]
results['moments'][3][5]
```

etc... through several hundred, so i'm not sure how to iterate that and keep the [5] at the next tier.

The reason i don't just use the full output of results['moments'] is i want to export this to excel, and if i just write  using csv_writer on just

```
results['moments']
```

it doesn't actually comma seperate the values so i end up with long bracketed values within Column 1, but if i go to the 3rd level it will be comma seperated when i output to excel.

### i'm sure there are several ways to resolve this issue.
see code below

```
response = session.get('http://xxxxxxxxxxxx', params=params)
     
results = response.json()

location = results['moments'][0][5]    
print location


with open('Location1.csv', 'wb') as test_file:
    csv_writer = csv.writer(test_file)
    for y in location:
        csv_writer.writerow(y)
```

Comment: Q is not understandable. At least provide an example of the json you get back from `session.get()`

Comment: I'd like to see incoming JSON and expected OUTPUT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of doing

```
results['moments'][0][5]
results['moments'][1][5]
results['moments'][2][5]
results['moments'][3][5]
```

You can use a simple list comprehension to do this for you, where you iterate on the length of the list `results['moments']`. Note that the other index remains fixed, as shown below:

```
locations = [results['moments'][i][5] for i in xrange(len(results['moments']))]
```

or

```
locations = [moment[5] for moment in results['moments']]
```

Comment: this is pretty close to what i was looking for. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?  (Assuming the code you pasted works.)

```
response = session.get('http://xxxxxxxxxxxx', params=params)
results = response.json()
for i in xrange(len(results['moments'])):
  location = results['moments'][i][5]
  with open('Location'+str(i+1)+'.csv', 'wb') as test_file:
    csv_writer = csv.writer(test_file)        
    for y in location:        
      csv_writer.writerow(y)
```